# How to use CSS selector in JavaScript to find element that includes a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

The correct way to give an element multiple classes is simply put spaces between them.  Right?

Then why does the selector `[class=CLASSNAME]` not work unless it's the only class?

`[class^=CLASSNAME]` works if the class is the first one.

But how to select all elements that possess a given class, regardless of the number or order of their classes?

I want to select all the elements with class `foo-bar`.  But the code below only selects the first one.

```js
const selector = '[class=foo-bar]';
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
console.log([...divs].map(div => div.textContent));
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar">foo</div>
<div class="foo-bar baz">bar</div>
<div class="baz foo-bar">baz</div>
```

Comment: That's an attribute selector not a class selector, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an attribute selector, it's matching against the entire attribute value as an ordinary string. It doesn't treat the `class` attribute specially, so it's not considered to be a list of classes that can be matched individually.

Just as in CSS, use `.classname` to match any class in the list.

```js
const selector = '.foo-bar';
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
console.log([...divs].map(div => div.textContent.trim()));
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar">foo</div>
<div class="foo-bar baz">bar</div>
<div class="baz foo-bar">baz</div>
```